# How to speed up the Bluetooth File Receive from Bluetooth device?

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, bluetooth

In the below, I read the files from the Bluetooth device. Is there is any way to improve the code and speed?

```
 using (FileStream fs = new FileStream(destination,
                                                FileMode.OpenOrCreate,
                                                FileAccess.ReadWrite))
                                            {
                                                byte[] firstByte = new byte[1] { (byte)readByte };
                                                 fs.Write(firstByte, 0, 1);

                                                // Size is idenitifed. Read till that size.
                                                for (int i = 1; i < fileSizeInBytes; i++)
                                                {
                                                    readByte = 0;
                                                    byte[] fb = new byte[1];
                                                    if ((readByte = inStream.Read(fb, 0, 1)) > 0)
                                                    {
                                                        fs.Write(fb, 0, readByte);

                                                    }
                                                }


                                            }
```

Comment: I would read more than one byte at a time, since you know the expected length. Context switching is expensive.

Comment: use bigger chunks of data - 1 byte at a time is going to be incredibly slow

Comment: @Jason Do you want to increase this buffer size  byte[] fb = new byte[1024];

Comment: it probably depends on the device and how much data it can accept.  You will need to check it's specs, figure it out by trial and error, or write an adaptive algorithm

Comment: @can anyone posts me best-optimized code for above  code

Comment: Did you try to read the file to the memory use `MemoryStream`. FileStream fs = new FileStream(binaryFilePath, FileMode.OpenOrCreate,
                                                FileAccess.ReadWrite);
            //Read all bytes into an array from the specified file.
            int nBytes = (int)fs.Length;
            byte[] byteArray = new byte[nBytes];
            int nBytesRead = fs.Read(byteArray, 0, nBytes);
            using (MemoryStream br = new MemoryStream(byteArray))
            {
             // your code
            }

Answer (score 0):

Try using this - it creates a new byte array of a larger size and copies the elements from yours.

```
 Array.Resize(ref readByte, 1024);
```

Comment: where I need to add this line. I can't understand what are you trying to say.

Comment: Please have a read of this page of [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.array.resize?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netframework-4.8#System_Array_Resize__1___0____System_Int32_). There's another resource with examples [here](https://www.dotnetperls.com/array-resize).

Comment: I understand this Array Resize but this does not suit to answer to my question @emmandemontford

Comment: Resizing the array should allow your byte array to be read quicker, as the bytes will be larger. Theoretically, this should improve your speed - sorry if this isn't what you needed.